# How to return api errors to Login Component in NextAuth.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

How to return API errors to Login Component in NextAuth.js.Actually, I am trying to pass the Errors back to Login Component in NextAuth(Credentials Provider). I am getting this object in console `error: "CredentialsSignin" ok: false status: 401 url: null [[Prototype]]: Object` Everything is working fine like I am able to log in, but when I am trying to handle errors coming from APIs, I am unable to handle them.

[...nextauth.js] File

```
export default (req, res) =>
NextAuth(req, res, {
    providers: [
      CredentialsProvider({
            authorize: async (credentials) => {
                try {
                    const data = {
                        email: credentials.email,
                        password: credentials.password
                    }
                    const user = await login(data);
                    console.log("401 Error",user.data);
                    if (user.data.status==200) {
                        console.log("200 data",user.data);
                         return Promise.resolve(user.data);
                      }else if(user.data.status==401){
                        // Here I wants to Handle Errors and return them back to My login Compenent
                      }
                } catch (error) {
                    if (error.response) {
                        console.log(error.response);
                        Promise.reject(new Error('Invalid Username  and Password combination'));
                    }
                }     
            },
             

        }),
        GoogleProvider({
          clientId: process.env.GOOGLE_ID,
          clientSecret: process.env.GOOGLE_SECRET,
        }),
    ],
    pages: {
      signIn: '/login',
    },
    callbacks: {
        jwt: async ({token,user})=>{
            
            if(user){
                token.userid = user.id; 
                token.name = user.username;
                token.token = user.token;
            }
            return token;
        },
        session: (session,token)=>{
            return session;  
        }
      },
      secret:"test",
      jwt:{
          secret:"test",
          encryption:true,
      },
    site: process.env.NEXTAUTH_URL || "http://localhost:3000",
    session: {
        jwt: true, 
        maxAge: 1 * 3 * 60 * 60, // 3 hrs
        updateAge: 24 * 60 * 60, // 24 hours
      }

});

 const login = async data => {
     
var config = {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        'corsOrigin': '*',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*"
    }
};
const url = 'api/auth/login';
const result = await axios.post(url,data,config);
return result;

};
```

Login Components

```
const LoginSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const enteredEmail = inputText.email;
    const enteredPassword = inputText.password;
   // console.log(enteredEmail);
    const result = await signIn("credentials", {
      redirect: false,
      email: enteredEmail,
      password: enteredPassword,
    });
     console.log("Final Result",result);
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it :
Try :

```
    // component.js
    const res = await signIn("credentials", {
    email: inputs.email,
    password: inputs.password,
    callbackUrl: `/`,
    redirect: false,
  });

  if (res?.error) {
    setLoading(false);
    Swal.fire("Invalid Login", "username or password is incorrect");
  }
```

and in Nextauth file you must throw an error if a user entred invalid credential!

```
    //[...nextauth].js
     const providers = [
        Providers.Credentials({
         name: "credentials",
         authorize: async (credentials) => {
         //statr try
        try {
          const user = await 
          axios.post(`${API_URL}/auth/local`, {
           identifier: credentials.email,
           password: credentials.password,
           });

        if (user) {
           return { status: "success", 
                 data:user.data };
      }
     } catch (e) {
      throw new Error("Not found ");
     }
     },
   }),
   ];
```

Comment: It won't work... as i am getting errors from API...

Comment: which api do you use ?

Comment: use try and cach block in you login function and you should return a value like an empty array and then check if the result from login function is an empty array then throw an error.

Comment: try{
const result = await axios.post(url,data,config);
return result;
}catch{
return []